# When click on button automatically sent to top of the website

Tags: javascript

When I click on the button on top of my website using a JavaScript the exact same second I press the button I get directly sent to the top of my website, how can I remove that and the same when closing the side nav.

```
 function openSlideMenu(){
  document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '250px';
  document.getElementById('main').style.marginLeft = '250px';       
}

function closeSlideMenu(){
  document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '0';
  document.getElementById('main').style.marginLeft = '0';
}
```

Comment: Are you using anchors (`<a>`) with `href` set to `#`?

Comment: If you're using an anchor tag and attaching your functions to the onclick event on it, you probably don't have the `href` value filled. That will cause the top navigation. What you need to do inside of each function is to do `ev.preventDefault()`, where `ev` is the event object passed into the arguments of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Your link has `href="#"` in it which sets an empty anchor on the page, jumping it to the top.

To prevent that behavior, prevent the default behavior on the onClick event.

```
 function openSlideMenu(event){
    event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: How do you know without that info being given in the OP? Even then, you gotta send the `event` inside the function.